# Mapping similar products in single product in price comparison website

Tags: mysql

I am making a price comparing website. I have data from different stores, but I could not find any way to map similar products to single product.

I have a table 'product1' like this .

```
  id       title                                               brandName    
|  8986 | Samsung Galaxy Ace                                 | Samsung   |       1 |
|  8983 | Samsung Galaxy Ace                                 | Samsung   |       1 |
|  6048 | Samsung Galaxy Ace                                 | Samsung   |       1 |
|  6109 | Samsung Galaxy Ace                                 | Samsung   |       1 |
|  9840 | Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos                            | Samsung   |       1 |
|  8905 | Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos                            | Samsung   |       1 |
|  9097 | Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos                            | Samsung   |       1 |
|   765 | Samsung galaxy Ace Duos S6802 ( Black)             | Samsung   |       2 |
|   766 | Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos S6802 (Chic White)         | Samsung   |       2 |
| 11880 | Samsung Galaxy Ace NXT                             | Samsung   |       1 |
| 11218 | Samsung Galaxy Ace NXT                             | Samsung   |       1 |
|   323 | Samsung Galaxy Ace Nxt G313H Black                 | Samsung   |       2 |
|   311 | Samsung Galaxy Ace Nxt G313H White                 | Samsung   |       2 |
|  9099 | Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus                            | Samsung   |       1 |
|  1153 | Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus S7500 Dark Blue            | Samsung   |       2 |
```

Now I want to map similar products; for example I need results like

```
title                                  brandIDs
Samsung Galaxy Ace             8986 , 8983 , 6048 , 6109
Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos        9840 , 8905 ,9097 ,  765 , 766
Samsung Galaxy Ace NXT         11880 , 11218 , 323 , 311
Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus        9099 , 1153
```

Is there any programming logic or mysql which can give me desired result? 
I tried different mysql clause i.e LIKE'%%' but it returns me whole data.

**Table schema :**

`CREATE TABLE`product1`(`
id`int(11) NOT NULL,`
title`varchar(50) NOT NULL,`
brandName`varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--

```
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (8986, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (8983, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (6048, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (6109, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (9840, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (8905, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (9097, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (765, 'Samsung galaxy Ace Duos S6802 ( Black)', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (766, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos S6802 (Chic White)', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (11880, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace NXT', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (11218, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace NXT', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (323, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace Nxt G313H Black', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (311, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace Nxt G313H White', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (9099, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus', 'Samsung');
INSERT INTO `product1` VALUES (1153, 'Samsung Galaxy Ace Plus S7500 Dark Blue', 'Samsung');
```

Can any body please tell me how can i achieve desired result in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basics you can do with a simple `GROUP BY`:

```
select
 title,
 group_concat(id) as brandIDs
from product1
group by title;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87532/1

But it will group only products with exactly the same `title`, no way to simply say in SQL that `Samsung Galaxy Ace Nxt G313H Black` and `Samsung Galaxy Ace Nxt G313H White` are the same.

You should normalize your table. You can use a separate table of `brands` which will save space from the multiplication of the names. And you can add some "hierarchy" of `brand`->`series`->`product` like `Samsung`->`Galaxy Ace Nxt`->`G313H Black` to make these queries easier.

Edit:
I tried to get exactly the results you show with MySQL string functions:

```
select
 substring_index(title,' ',4),
 group_concat(id) as brandIDs
from product1
group by substring_index(title,' ',4);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87532/6

Comment: Hi @jkavalik . Thanks for the valuable answer .  But isn't there any way to get data separated from spaces using SQL as you mentioned in your answer ? I am trying to solve this problem from last week but did not get anything useful . although you have given me perfect direction .

Comment: There are [String functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html) available in MySQL and with them you might define some expression for the `GROUP BY` to do what you want. But it would probably be easier to do that in php/python/java or any other language you use.

Comment: @DeepakRathore added a query using `substring_index` to give the exact results you wanted.

Comment: Hey man . You are super man for me . you made my day . Edit part is the solution of my problem . A big thank to you . Thanks man @jkavalik